# How do I write a query to get new donors, second year donors, ...?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate from a table for each year the number of new donors, second-year-donors (2 years in a row), multi-year-donors (>= 3 years in a row), lapsed donors and reactivated donors (lapsed donors who have given again this year). I am not sure whether this is really possible in one query. However, even if I have to write a single query for each of these segments there must be a better way to run the query for each year.

For reasons of simplicity, let's assume the TABLE *donations* consists only of the donor_id and the donation year

```
donor_id      date_year
1             2003
1             2004
2             2003
2             2005
2             2006
2             2007
3             2005
```

This is what I would like to know in the end:

```
year  new_donors  second_year_donors  multi_year_donors  lapsed_donors  reactivated_donors
2003  2           0                   0                  0              0
2004  0           1                   0                  1              0
2005  1           0                   0                  1              1
```

I can write the query for new donors:

```
SELECT d.first_year AS 'year',
       COUNT(d.id) AS 'new_donors'
  FROM (SELECT donor_id AS 'id', 
               MIN(date_year) AS 'first_year'
          FROM donations
         GROUP BY donor_id) d      
 GROUP BY year
 ORDER BY year ASC;
```

However, I have no idea how to write an elegant query that counts all donors who donated two years in a row but not more than that. I am pretty sure there must be a better way than to run this query for each year.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.donor_id) AS 'second_year_donors'
  FROM donations d
 WHERE year = 2005
   AND d.donor_id IN (
                      SELECT donor_id   
                        FROM donations 
                       WHERE year = 2004
                     )
   AND d.donor_id NOT IN (
                          SELECT donor_id
                            FROM donations
                           WHERE year = 2003
                         );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some queries to get you started. I didn't test rigorously, but you should be able to rejigger these slightly to come up with queries for new_donors and lapsed_donors as well:

```sql
select this.donor_year, count(*) as second_year_donors
from donations as this
join donations as prev on this.donor_year - 1 = prev.donor_year and this.donor_id = prev.donor_id
group by this.donor_year;

select this.donor_year, count(*) as third_year_donors
from donations as this
join donations as prev on this.donor_year - 1 = prev.donor_year and this.donor_id = prev.donor_id
join donations as prev2 on this.donor_year - 2 = prev2.donor_year  and this.donor_id = prev2.donor_id
group by this.donor_year;

select this.donor_year, count(distinct this.donor_id) as reactivated_donors
from donations as this
left join donations as prev on this.donor_year - 1 = prev.donor_year and this.donor_id = prev.donor_id
join donations as past on this.donor_year - 1 > past.donor_year and this.donor_id = past.donor_id
where prev.donor_id is null
group by this.donor_year;
```