# SQL Query to give total repeat donors from year to year?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Our Fund Development team wants to know how many of our donors are repeats from year to year. So how many who donated in 2023 also donated in 2022, 2021, etc. I'm assuming I'd use COUNT(*) or GROUP BY for this but not sure. Sample table below

| ID | Date | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 3/2/21 | 2021 |
| 54321 | 5/3/22 | 2022 |
| 54321 | 7/10/23 | 2023 |

Ideally it would spit out a table like this:

| Year | New Donors | Second Year Donors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023 | 0 | 1 |

Tried a few variations of COUNT(*) and GROUP BY. Can get the total count of each donation by Contact Name or by Year but seem to be unsuccessful bringing them together.

Also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099099/how-do-i-write-a-query-to-get-new-donors-second-year-donors) but it's giving me a syntax error whenever I try to add in the second chunk of syntax.